# Mailcore2 "unable to parse response from server" – how can I log the messages to/from the server so I can figure out what isn't parsing?

Tags: ios, debugging, logging, mailcore2

I'm getting an NSError:
`Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=3 "Unable to parse response from server." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to parse response from server.}`.  I'm not quite sure how to figure out what actual messages are causing this, and would like to dig in.  However I'm not sure how to figure out what mailcore2 is sending to and getting back from the server.

My guess is I'm actually calling something with a wrong parameter and causing mailcore2 to make an invalid request and the server is generating an error that doesn't parse right, but I won't rule out other possibilities (like the server actually generating an actual unparsable message with no provocation, or something).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that MailCore2 was open source software, so maybe you can re-compile it with its DEBUG flag set.  Then you could get some logs to work with.

It is also possible to set the Xcode scheme environment to [enable network diagnostics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/debugging_https_problems_with_cfnetwork_diagnostic_logging) in case you can identify the issue based upon the network communication.

You could try running your app with the Instruments tool.  This has a Network instrument that also gives insights on the network traffic.

Lastly you could try a Man-in-the-Middle Proxy, such as Charles Proxy.

To help develop a theory you could see where the software assigns a parsing error `pError = ErrorParse` such as [Moving Messages Parse Error](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/7417b2e8dd7e2c028aadb72056e4d1428c0627c4/src/core/imap/MCIMAPSession.cpp#L1935).  Then you can have more focussed experimentation.